# How do I pass an argument into Async.RunSynchronously?

Tags: f#, lego-mindstorms

How do I pass an argument into Async.RunSynchronously?

**I am attempting to do the following:**

```
Async.RunSynchronously (moveAsync brick)
```

Of course, this does not compile:

> The value or constructor 'brick' is not defined

I updated my code but am still running into the same issue regarding passing in an argument into Async.RunSynchronously

**Client:**

open LegoCommands

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    connectAsync |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
    moveAsync    |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
    speakAsync   |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**Domain:**

Currently my code works by setting an external member variable and having my functions refer to it.

```
let brick = Brick(UsbCommunication())
```

I don't want this.

```
module LegoCommands

open Lego.Ev3.Core
open Lego.Ev3.Desktop
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Arguments

let brick = Brick(UsbCommunication())

let awaitTask (task: Task) = task |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                                  |> Async.Ignore
let connectAsync = async {
    do! brick.ConnectAsync() |> awaitTask }

let moveAsync = async {
    do! brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(motors, power, uint32 duration, breakEnabled) |> awaitTask }

let speakAsync = async {
    do! brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(volume, frequency, duration) |> awaitTask }
```

Comment: Why doesn't it compile? I'd expect it to. Also, looks better ;)

Comment: You might want to link the two questions together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I did wrong.

But I no longer observe the error.

**Client:**

```
open LegoCommands
open Lego.Ev3.Core
open Lego.Ev3.Desktop

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let brick = Brick(UsbCommunication())
    brick |> connectAsync |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
    brick |> moveAsync    |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
    brick |> speakAsync   |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

**Domain:**

```
module LegoCommands

open Lego.Ev3.Core
open Lego.Ev3.Desktop
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Arguments

let awaitTask (task: Task) = task |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
                                  |> Async.Ignore
let connectAsync (brick:Brick) = async {
    do! brick.ConnectAsync() |> awaitTask }

let moveAsync (brick:Brick) = async {
    do! brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(motors, power, uint32 duration, breakEnabled) |> awaitTask }

let speakAsync (brick:Brick) = async {
    do! brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(volume, frequency, duration) |> awaitTask }
```

**Parameters:**

```
module Arguments
open Lego.Ev3.Core

let volume = 50
let frequency = uint16 3000
let duration = uint16 333
let power = 100
let motors = OutputPort.B ||| OutputPort.C
let breakEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

On the third line of "client" you're using `brick`, which is not yet defined at that point.

```
Async.RunSynchronously (connectAsync brick)
```

Same happens on the last line of "domain":

```
Async.RunSynchronously (moveAsync(brick))
```

The error message tells you exactly this: `brick` is not defined.

Comment: @ Fyodor - The client actually compiles. Can you elaborate on what I need to do to make the brick defined. I am trying to learn F#. Hence, I'm not a professional F# developer.

Comment: To get `brick` defined, you need to define it, like you do on the first line of `main`. If the "client" compiles, it means you've defined `brick` somewhere in the code above that you're not showing us.